# How do i make a marker show only on road, rather than showing it on houses and buildings?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have been able to show my current location on the map. I have been able to use the location manager and fused location api to display my current location. Here i am unable to maintain the positioning of the marker in the map, i.e; When ever i move on road just to check the movement of the marker, the marker also moves but some times it goes over houses and buildings. How do i make the marker stay put on road. If you check the Uber app, the car that comes to pick you up always stays on the road it never goes on top of the houses and buildings.

Kindly advice me on how to make the marker move only on the road.

Thanks in advance.
Sidharth

Comment: try to use road api https://github.com/googlemaps/roads-api-samples

Comment: Roads API Nearest Road should help with this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/nearest